# Sending WIN+CTRL+SHIFT+B using C#

Tags: c#, windows-10, keystroke

I'm trying so simulate keystroke combination <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to *Windows 10* using *Visual C# 2017*.

This key combination restarts the video driver, and i can confirm it works when i do it manually, but can't get a way to do it using C#.

I have even tried http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ like this :

```
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.LCONTROL);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.LSHIFT);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.VK_B);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.VK_B);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.LSHIFT);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.LCONTROL);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN);
```

and like this :

```
InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(
            new[] { VirtualKeyCode.LCONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.LSHIFT },
            new[] { VirtualKeyCode.VK_B }
        );
```

Any help on a working solution is welcomed !

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this with a few combinations and I'm wondering if some commands just aren't allowed.

For example `LWIN` + `VK_E` works fine for opening file explorer but `LWIN` + `VK_L` to lock the machine does not. `LCONTROL` + `ESCAPE` is working when trying to open the start menu, as is `LWIN` on its own. Maybe what you're trying to do is seen as potentially "too risky" to be handled in this way.

As an aside, I also ran Visual Studio as admin to make sure it wasn't a user permissions thing, but that made no difference for me.

You might be able to [glean something from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500411/force-windows-video-driver-reload-is-it-possible-at-all) which is looking at forcing the video driver to reload via a different method.