# Deleting Locked Files & Folders

Tags: c#, file-io, delete-file, system.io.directory

I am writing an application that updates some drivers. However the drivers are "in use" and can't be deleted unless I restart my computer.

So how can I write an application to delete these locked drivers without restarting the PC. IF Restarting MUST occur then how can I relaunch my application automatically when the computer restarts and delete those files?

Comment: Incidentally, replacing drivers is one of the major reasons Windows still requires reboots.  Now, some drivers don't seem to need them anymore (nVidia drivers don't prompt for a reboot, they just disable the display momentarily).

Comment: @R. Bemrose: If I understand correctly, this works by separating the driver up into a core that stays loaded and the actual meat of the driver, which can be unloaded and replaced.  In other words, OP may not have any options.

Comment: Well they're printer drivers and printers aren't always in use. 

I learnt how to spooler service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Windows, you can "schedule" moving/deleting files around on a reboot by pinvoking the [`MoveFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240%28VS.85%29.aspx) API (Or the registry as described).

Answer (score 0):

If you can disable the hardware that's using the drivers, this might allow the driver to be unloaded and replaced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programatically-enable-disable-device