# Disable USB port from access smart-phone memory (without Group policy) in C#

Tags: c#, windows, usb, registry, smartphone

Hi I am currently working on an application to Disable/Enable USB port programmatically in C#

I have found the following code snippet to Enable/disable the USB port. It's working fine with normal USB Sticks. But unfortunately **its not disabling the Smartphone's memory card access.**

```
//disable USB storage...
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", "Start", 4, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord); 

//enable USB storage...
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", "Start", 3, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

I have googled for a better solution to solve this issue. I found some suggestions to use group policy for achieve the same. But my application is not intent to use the group policies. SO is there any solution is available like **edit any registry key** to achieve the Smart phone's memory access restriction programmaticaly in **c#**?

Comment: Looks like you need a reboot. Have a look here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478042/c-sharp-disable-enable-usb-ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to solve this issue by registry value change. The details are as follows,

For Disable USB port from access Smart-phone memory as well as Memory Sticks:

created the **DWORD** parameter **Deny_All** with the **value 00000001** in the registry **key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices**.

For Allow Access:

created the **DWORD** parameter **Deny_All** with the **value 00000000** in the registry **key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices**.

Note:- **To effect the access permission change**, we have to **restart the PC**

The C# Code Snippet is as follows,

For Allow Access:

Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices", "Deny_All", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

For Restrict the Access:

Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices", "Deny_All", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);