# Can the setup api be used to tell if a device is enabled

Tags: setupapi

I know how to use the Setup API to enable and disable devices.  What I need to know is, can I use this same API to determine if a device is enabled/disabled?  I think the real question is how to use it thusly because Microsoft's devcon uses the Setup API for its manipulation of hardware and that program will tell you if a device is enabled or disabled (as does the Device Manager).  How is this done?  My research of the Setup API methods to this point doesn't show a clear answer.

Andy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This API from MS has got to be among the least used, understood and worst documented.  As I mentioned in my original post, the Setup API can be used to enable/disable hardware.  So, I thought I would take a few moments and supply the community with how I finally figured out how to check the status of hardware.

So, the short answer: you don't do this from the Setup API.  Of course, this makes sense.  After all, since you can change the devices state, i.e. enable or disable, using the Setup API: it naturally follows that you'd have to use a completely different API to determine the device's current state.  Now, enter the Configuration Manager 32 API.  To enable/disable hardware, you have to use the Setup API, but to figure out what state the hardware is in, you have to use the ConfigMgr 32 API (#include cfgmgr32.h).  Makes sense, right?

There may be other ways of doing this, but here's what I did.

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>

GUID driveGuid = {0x4d36e967, 0xe325, 0x11ce,
    {0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18}};

// first, get a list of hardware you're interested in using Setup API
HDEVINFO hDevs(SetupDiGetClassDevs(&driveGuid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT));
if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hDevs)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("unable to build a list of hardware");
}

/* this struct has the dev instance ID that the CFG MGR API wants.
 * The struct must be must be inited to the size of the struct,
 * the cbSize member, all others should be 0
 */
SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfo = {sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA)};
DWORD index = 0;
LONG devStatus = 0, devProblemCode = 0;
char devId[256];
memset(devId, 0, 256)
while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevs, index++, &devInfo))
{
    // use Config Mgr to get a nice string to compare against
    CM_Get_Device_ID(devInfo.DevInst, devId, 256, 0);

    /* use whatever mechanism you like to search the string
     * to find out if it's the hardware you're after
     */
    if((std::string(devId)).find("MyHardware") != std::string::npos)
    {
        // goody, it's the hardware we're looking for
        CM_Get_DevNode_Status(&devStatus, &devProblemCode, devInfo.DevInst, 0);

        /* if the call to getting the status code was successful,
         * do something meaningful with the data returned.
         * The fun part of this is that the return codes aren't
         * really documented on MSDN.  You'll have to look
         * through the CfgMgr32.h file.  Incidentally, these values
         * are what are shown in the Device Manager when you look
         * at the device's status.
         */
    }
}

SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevs);
```

You'll have to figure out the GUID for the hardware you're after by searching through the list found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Some of these, at least, are predefined in various Windows headers.  However, at this point, I know of very few and have only stumbled onto them by accident.

Relevant links to the functions used above:
[SetupDiDestroyDevieInfoList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[CM_Get_DevNode_Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538514%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[CM_Get_Device_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[SetupDiGetClassDevs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[SP_DEVINFO_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: What flags are you using for determining "enabled" and "disabled"? Is `DN_STARTED` sufficient?

Comment: It's been some time since I was working with this (2012).  A quick check at the header file (cfg.h actually) and memory says that, yes, DN_STARTED should be enough for "enabled" or "disabled".  In reality, in this context, "enabled" simply means that the driver for this device is started: "disabled" means it isn't.

Comment: Your sarcasm is 100% appreciated after I have also spent days trying to figure out how to get the device's current state using Setup API. Thanks, Microsoft! But no seriously, thank you @AndrewFalanga

Comment: A few years too late, you're welcome @TamBui