# How do I enable/disable recording audio devices?

Tags: c#, audio

Is there a way to enable/disable recording audio devices in C#? I don't mean muting and unmuting them.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been posted at different places on SO, anyways, have a look at this application, this might help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HardwareHelper.aspx

also visit [Win32 API function to programmatically enable/disable device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programatically-enable-disable-device)