# SetupDI API enabling/disabling doesnt work on XP

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to enable/disable CD-Rom Drives programmatically using the SetupDI APIs as was suggested in this thread
[Win32 API function to programmatically enable/disable device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programmatically-enable-disable-device)

It works great on Win7 or Win8 but somehow I cant get it to work on XP. It lets me disable the Device but as soon as it is disabled, it doesnt let me Re-enable it.

I'm using ManagementObjectCollection to get the DeviceIDs of all CD/DVD Drives but if the Drive is disabled the ID doesnt Show up.

Any Help is much appreciated!! Thx

PS: Yes I know XP is no longer supported :D