# Com port Disable/Enable Programmatically C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

Where i can get the instance id of Com_port? I tried in device manager but those are not working

```
string instance_Path = @"VID_12D1&PID_140C&MI_02";
DeviceHelper.SetDeviceEnabled(mouseGuid, instance_Path, true);
```

Comment: What is "mouseGuid"? Are the process working with administrator rights?

Comment: yeah i logged with admin login only

Comment: I mean, you must run a process with elevated privileges in order to enable/disable devices with it (unless you are using windows xp).

Comment: can you please help to run process with privilege

Comment: What do you mean "are not working"? You get UnauthorizedAccessException if the problem is the access right. Could it be you're just specifying a wrong GUID?

Answer (score 1):

This question is virtually a duplicate - [Win32 API function to programmatically enable/disable device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programmatically-enable-disable-device)

"mouseGuid" might be pasted from there. I suppose you're specifying a wrong GUID for the COM port. You can see the correct one in the Device Manager, Details tab -> choose "Class Guid" from the dropdown menu.

Having troubles messing with WinAPI, you can use a library (e.g. [Hardware Helper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21503/Hardware-Helper-Library-for-C)) or an external tool ([DevCon](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311272)).