# How to disable a specific usb port com2 c# 64 bit

Tags: c#, c++, .net, serial-port, serial-communication

I have tried to disable com port by using

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(
    @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR",
    "Start",
    4,
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord
); 

//enable USB storage...
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(
    @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR",
    "Start",
    3,
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord
);
```

but doesn't work in 64 bit pc.

Is there any other solution to disable com port in 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Eugh.  Don't do this.  Use [`SetupDiSetClassInstallParams`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610140/138200) or [WMI + `devcon`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/25/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-find-and-disable-webcams/) or really anything other than editing the registry!

<sub>But to use registry you need to specify [`RegistryView.Registry64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview(v=vs.110).aspx), or clear the [Prefer 32 bit](http://www.neovolve.com/2015/07/31/disable-prefer-32-bit/) flag in the project properties</sub>

Comment: Is there any programminmg way we can disablecom port  in 64 bit. If i would like to use registry how i will do that.