# Disable touchpad from acting as mouse while keeping HID_USAGE_DIGITIZER_TOUCH_PAD

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouse, touchpad

I made a program to process raw touchpad data using HID_USAGE_DIGITIZER_TOUCH_PAD. It works but the problem is that I need to also disable the touchpad from acting as a mouse. All the methods I found also disable HID_USAGE_DIGITIZER_TOUCH_PAD.

Comment: Could you provide more information? A [mcve] for both the code you are using, and your attempts to filter input would be very helpful in devising an answer. For what it's worth, I played around with this for a bit, and was able to filter out mouse messages generated in response to touch input from a touch display. That same code didn't do anything to input from a touchpad, though.

Comment: Hi Kuri0, where HID_USAGE_DIGITIZER_TOUCH_PAD comes from? [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programmatically-enable-disable-device).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I think that disabling the device like that would break HID_USAGE_DIGITIZER_TOUCH_PAD too.HID_USAGE_DIGITIZER_TOUCH_PAD is from raw input API

Comment: @IInspectable haven't made any attempts to filter. program is just one which reads raw input from HID_USAGE_DIGITIZER_TOUCH_PAD and then uses it.