# How to Enable/Disable a Device in Device Manager in Windows through its API?

Tags: windows, scripting, autohotkey

I started learning AutoHotKey and wanted to know if it was possible to write a script that allows me to enable/disable a device in device manager without having to manually unplug/plug the device from the computer. I wasn't sure if I needed to run the script on the command line and somehow access the API of the Device Manager through there and write one/two lines of code that allows to enable/disable. I did stumble across the API: `DeviceIoControl`. I think I can get the handle of the device by using the `CreateFile` function that has the name of the device. The problem is I'm not sure how to properly use the name of the device in order to enable/disable it.

Comment: `DeviceIoControl` is for communication with a device, not the device manager.

Comment: @IInspectable If its with the communication with the device then in theory would it be possible to enable/disable it? I assume DeviceIoControl cuts/restore communication from the device to the computer?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610140/3813732) should probably do the trick? If you'll have trouble converting it over to AHK, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a command line utility that does just that. Easy to call with AHK:

```
Run 'pnputil /disable-device "HID\VID_045E&PID_028E&IG_00\7&2F160D0&0&0000"'
Run 'pnputil /enable-device "HID\VID_045E&PID_028E&IG_00\7&2F160D0&0&0000"'
```

To toggle a device:

```
ToggleDevice(device_id) {
  command := 'pnputil /enum-devices /instanceid "' device_id '" | find "Status"'
  result := ComObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(A_ComSpec ' /C "' command '"').StdOut.ReadAll()
  status := InStr(result, "Disabled") ? 'enable' : 'disable'
  Run 'pnputil /' status '-device "' device_id '"'
  return status = "enable"
}
```

Example:

```
#f:: {
  FIGHTBOX_DEVICE_ID := "HID\VID_045E&PID_028E&IG_00\7&2F160D0&0&0000"
  enabled := ToggleDevice(FIGHTBOX_DEVICE_ID)
  Tooltip "Device " (enabled ? "en" : "dis") "abled!"
  SetTimer () => ToolTip(), -3000
}
```

(Better late that never :P)