Disabling a physically connected devices which are involved in an IO operation
Problem statement:
I'm trying to disable a device using the setup apis, but sometimes I'm experiencing an error due to it is involved in IO operations. Im looking for a way to make a device behave like it is removed physically or in some way to abruptly stop all the current IO operations of a device. Suggest a solution suitable for all kind of devices. I have seen a solution for ejecting a disk drive using the eject control code, however it is not working for other devices like wpd's.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programmatically-enable-disable-device

Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I'm encountering an error when the device is undergoing IO operations. When I attempt to disable it in the Device Manager, the devices are asking for a system restart to take effect. Therefore, I'm exploring a way to abruptly stop all IO operations of the device. I believe that once the IO operations are stopped, disabling the device will work as intended.

It is not recommended. Generally, the scenario that a device is undergoing IO operations involves kernel and also is out of the capability of Windows API. You can Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app about this concern.
